# Facebook "Like" button counter suddenly vanished, why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, counter

A few weeks ago I added a XFBML Facebook ["Like" button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) with counter on a website. The counter worked fine and everyday the number of "Likes" increased.

Suddenly a few days ago the counter vanished just leaving the "Like" button alone.

When using the [Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) check I am suddenly receiving an error message which did not show before stating that either "fb:app_id" or "fb:admins" need to be declared. All other values are fine and as required.

Changing to the iframe version does not make a difference.

My question is basically why it worked before and not anymore? Is it due to hitting a certain amount of "Likes" or similar?

Obviously I can simply register with FB and add those parameters but that is not my intention.

A work around could be to access e.g. http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://google.com/ and grab the data from there. Still it does not explain why it worked some weeks ago and no longer does.

Any suggestions or feedback is much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: can you show some code?
the like button code that is.

Comment: @Rephael Herjcovici Simply follow the first link in the question. It is just what FB provided in their wizard. Nothing changed from my side.

Comment: i wanted to see in your head tags if you have the fb:admins or fb:app_id

Comment: @Dementic Sorry if I wasn't too clear. I did not have either "fb:app_id" or "fb:admins" before and it was working fine.

Comment: in Step 2 of the link provided,
you generate a Open Graph tags which contains the fb:app_id or fb:admins.
so unless you did just half of the instructions and a bug made it work, or... i dont know. :)

Comment: The counter is back now (still without "fb:app_id" or "fb:admins" tags)... after a week being gone. Again I have not touched any code whatsoever. Facebook must be playing on their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The counter is back now (still without "fb:app_id" or "fb:admins" tags)... after a week being gone.

Again, I have not touched any code whatsoever.

Facebook must be playing on their end.

Comment: interesting.
must have been a problem on their side.
im glad it was solved :D